# Javascript & Regex: split string on an instance of text

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string, and a string I want to match against:

```
var extendedText = "the Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog"
var matchText = "the"

var regex = new RegExp(`(?=[^.*${matchText}.*$])|(?<=[^.*${matchText}.*$])`);

var splitText = extendedText.split(regex);
```

I want to split the string, keeping the delimiter and end up with something like this:

```
'the',
' quick brown fox jumps over '
'the'
' lazy dog'
```

The Regex above currently splits out every character however, giving me this:

```
'the', '', ' ', '', 'q', '', 'u', '', 'i', '', 'c',........'r', '', ' ', '' 'the', '' ' ' '' 'l', '','a'........etc etc
```

How can I stop the non-matching text from being split out into a list of characters and instead return a list of the substrings? Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Comment: You don't want `[]` around the match text. That's for matching individual characters, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to,

```
(?=${matchText})|(?<=${matchText})
```

And this will work as you desire.

```js
var extendedText = "the Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog"
var matchText = "the"

var regex = new RegExp(`(?=${matchText})|(?<=${matchText})`);

var splitText = extendedText.split(regex);

console.log(splitText);
```

Also, if you don't want your match text to match partially, then use \b and change your regex to,

```
(?=\b${matchText})\b|\b(?<=${matchText})\b
```

```js
var extendedText = "the Quick Brown Fox there Jumps Over the Lazy Dog"
var matchText = "the"

var regex = new RegExp(`(?=\\b${matchText}\\b)|(?<=\\b${matchText}\\b)`);

var splitText = extendedText.split(regex);

console.log(splitText);
```

Comment: ++ good use of look arounds

Comment: I just tried correcting OP's regex :)

Comment: And answer it you did, thanks for the help! I did end up requiring the full match as well so thanks for that addition :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a split solution that uses a capture group:

```js
var extendedText = "the Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog";
var matchText = "the";
var arr = 
extendedText.split(new RegExp(`(\\b${matchText}\\b)`)).filter(Boolean);

console.log(arr);

/*[
'the',
' Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over ',
'the',
' Lazy Dog'
]*/
```

`filter(Boolean)` has been used to filter out empty results from array.